# Why does Rails 4 scaffold create json.jbuilder files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've generated a new rails 4 (rc1) project using `rails new` and generated a scaffold using `rails g scaffold`.

As expected it has created the migration, controller and all required view files.

It has also created show.json.jbuilder and index.json.jbuilder.

I assume this is to aid json generation from models. The controller contains format.json invocations as well.

**Question: why does it require json and which part of the generated application is using json? It doesn't look like (for me) the views are using json to render anything, seems they are rendered on the server side (@model variables are used in the views to get the content).**

The edge guides (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/) don't see to mention jbuilder and why it's needed there.

Thanks in advance! Please let me know if I can clarify the question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To answer the "why" part:

The relevance of scaffolding in Rails has somewhat shifted over the years. It is no longer meant to generate necessary code which couldn't be abstracted away easily. Today it is mostly an **educational** tool to provide you with a somewhat dynamic example and demonstrate best practices. (That's also the reason why they are sprinkled with comments with disputable usefulness)

In other words the generated files are meant to tell you:

**If you are going to use Rails, here is a good way how you could do it.**

or in your specific case:

**If you are going to use JBuilder, here is a good way to generate JSON.**

They are *not* meant to tell: "This is how it must be done." or "You have to keep all the generated stuff because it's necessary."

Comment: `GET` method on JSON format (generated on Rails scaffold by default) is not a good practice because of JSON Hijacking.

Answer (score 19):

As said before, Rails 4 seems to generate the files as a way to have a template for responding to a JSON query. So let's say you have "scaffolded" a model `Car`, then it will respond with a HTML page and a detail view of car (id 1) if you go `/car/1`.

Then if you go to `/car/1.json`, it will render the `show.json.jbuilder` file. There also seems to be some kind of automatic mechanism as the `show` method is empty when scaffolding:

```
def show
end
```

Comment: at the top of the controller there is a 
`before_action :set_modelname` 
  
which calls the private method 
  
`def set_activity
      @modelname = Modelname.find(params[:id])
    end`

Comment: `Then if you go to /car/1.json, it will render the show.json.jbuilder file` nicely said

Answer (score 14):

Rails 4 scaffold generator creates jbuilder files because the gem 'Jbuilder' is in the Gemfile. If you remove this from your `Gemfile` this functionality will stop.

Answer (score 10):

[Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) gem included in RoR 4 by default. You could read about it on its page. There is a cast about it: [Railscasts #320](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder).

Comment: Thx for this. I am using RABL and it wasn't generating JSON from the .rabl files. Didn't realize jbuilder was getting in the way. Commented it out and it all worked perfectly.